# Question about Double Jump and Collision in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have just started to learn how to make a simple 2D platformer game in Unity, and I have watched [Blackthornprod 2D Platformer movement video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGDeafTx5ug&index=3&list=PLBIb_auVtBwCP0_ZTv1a6P9fnn_CcKrq7) to learn how to make a character move and jump. So far I was able to understand most of the video, however, I have met some problem with the Jumping part.

Now, as far as I understand in his video, to make a character jump, I need to detect whether the character is touching the ground or not. To do that I need to create a little circle under the player's feet to see if it overlaps the ground, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HnNS.png)

So, here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float JumpForce;       // jumping force

    private bool isGrounded;      //if the player is touching the ground
    public Transform GroundCheck; //object that contains the position of the 
                                  //"circle"
    public LayerMask GroundLayer; //the layer that the "circle" collide with
    public float radius;          //radius of the circle
    public float BaseNumOfJumps;  //maximum number of jumps
    private float NumOfJumps;     //current number of jumps


    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        NumOfJumps = BaseNumOfJumps;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //check the collision between the "circle" and the ground
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(GroundCheck.position, 
        radius,GroundLayer);

       //here is the horizontal movement update part, but they are 
       //irrelevant so I cut them off

    }

    void Update()
    {
        //if the player touches the ground, reset the number of jumps
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            NumOfJumps = BaseNumOfJumps;
        }

        //when jumping, decrease the number of jumps
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && NumOfJumps > 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * JumpForce;
            NumOfJumps--;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is where the problem began, the actual maximum number of jumps is always higher than the value I entered. So for example, if I put BaseNumOfJumps = 2, then I can jump 3 times instead of 2, similarly, if BaseNumOfJumps = 1 then I can jump 2 times and so on.

After a while, I found out that because the size of the circle is always a tad bit larger than the actual player's feet, when I jump, the was a moment in between where the player's feet is int the air, but the circle still overlaps with the ground, which reset the current number of jumps (aka NumOfJumps in my code) and make my character able to do one more jump than the number entered in BaseNumOfJumps. **I don't know if it was true or not**, [but here was what I imagined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY6a6.png). [This comment under the video also described the same problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vsokx.png)

While Blackthornprod already mentioned those value as "extra jumps", so if I enter "1" in that value, I will jump twice, "2" and I will jump 3 times, etc. I still met some difficulties in making the number of jumps consistent. What if my character just slides off the ground without jumping [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWyA1.png)? The circle wouldn't collide with the ground and I will be able to jump the exact number of jumps I entered in BaseNumOfJumps, in short:

If the maximum number of jumps I entered is 2, I will be able to **(again, this is just my guess, so I could likely be wrong**):

- [Jump 3 times when my character is on the ground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/359mg.png)
- [Jump 2 times when my character runs off the ground and doesn't collide with it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y167U.png)

Which of course create some inconsistency. I have searched other tutorials about jumping and colliding, but most of them either use other forms of checking collision (like OnCollisionStay, OnCollisionEnter) or use the same method I used but didn't go deep into explaining it (So basically they are the same as in Blackthornprod's video)

So how can I solve this problem, how can I change the radius of the "circle" so that it leaves the ground the same moment the player's feet leaves when they jump? Or should I use other forms of collision checking like I mentioned before, and if so, what are their difference and which is the most effective?

This is my first question here, I know it's a bit long and confusing since I am not familiar with English, but I will really appreciate if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's get a conceptual understanding of what we want to do. We want the player to have the same number of jumps regardless of whether or not they jump first (using one jump) or fall (NOT using one jump). However, one simple truth is certain: **our grounded jump cannot be used if we are not on the ground.** We can achieve this by keeping track of grounded jumps and midair jumps separately.

Now, the only question we need to ask to allow the use of a grounded jump is whether or not the player is on the ground. The only questions we need to ask to allow the use of a bonus jump are whether or not the player is in the air and whether or not the player has jumps left.

All that remains is to determine whether or not the player has jumps left. If they fell, we can just count how many jumps out of their total jumps they get. If they jumped, we can count how many jumps out of their total number of jumps **minus one.**

All of this considered gives us the following logic:

```
int numberOfJumps = 1; //Or however many you want.
bool initiallyJumped = false; // jump checking

//Other stuff
void Update()
{
    //Reset jumps BEFORE considering allowing jumps
    if(isGrounded)
    {
        initiallyJumped = false;
        resetJumpCounter();
    }
    
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        if(!initiallyJumped && isGrounded)
        {
            jump();
            initallyJumped = true;
        }
        else
        {
            int jumpsRemaining = numberOfJumps;
            if(initiallyJumped)
            {
                jumpsRemaining--;
            }
            
            if(numberOfJumps > jumpsRemaining)
            {
                jump();
                numberOfJumps--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the initial jump is used only if it has not been used AND the player is on the ground. Bonus jumps are used in any other scenario. However, the number of bonus jumps is decreased by one if we jumped initially.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I still don't understand how the intial jump would work if the character doesn't start his jump from the ground. So normally the player can go into midair via jumping from the ground, but what if the platform just... suddenly falls off? The player can only access the bonus jumps as he is still in midair, but not the intial ground jump and can only jump, let say, twice instead of 3 times if he start jumping from the ground, because, as you said, only bonus jumps can be used if player is in midair.

Comment: If a platform just slides out from under the player, 'if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))' will be true, but 'isGrounded' will be false. Thus, the player will use only bonus jumps. I thought that that's what you were looking for. Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Also, I noticed that my proposed system has a bug in it that will prevent the player from getting bonus jumps if they hold down the jump button after landing for some reason and then fall off of something. I'm going to do a real quick edit to remedy this.

Comment: The edits are completed. I'm technically giving the initial jump back as the player rises, but I also explicitly check if they are on the ground to use their initial jump, so it's safe--this initial jump could not be used as a bonus unless they pressed the jump button twice very, very quickly. Even if they did manage this nearly impossible feat, the difference in jump height would be almost impossible to notice. But if it is still a problem, we could move the jump circle up a tiny bit so that the bottom of the circle, not the center of the circle, is at the bottom of the player's feet.

Comment: Again, thank you a lot for helping me, I have actually rewatched the video and also found some other videos, and they actually used similar solution to yours. Now I am able to understand part of the problem, however, what I meant in my previous comment was that I want my player to be able to do the intial jump without being on the ground to begin with. So if the platform just slides off the player's feet I want him to be able to access the intial jump just like when he is on the ground, so even if isGrounded == false, he can still do the intial jump. Sorry if I try to complicate things up.

Comment: Haha, whoops! Sorry! Solving this shouldn't be TOO hard... let me whip something up real quick.

Comment: OK, I edited the code. It follows the same general structure, but there's one extra if-statement.

Comment: I think I would still meet the first problem of the Player gaining an unwanted extra jump due to the intial jump being reset right after the player jumped because of the size of the collision circle. But I have searched for a while a figured out how to make a timer so there would be a "blank" moment between the intial jump and the if(isGrounded) function, I put the timer in while following your code and it worked perfectly now. Many thanks, it wouldn't be possible without your help.

Comment: You are correct; the initial jump would be reset. However, since we ALSO check to see if they are on the ground, this won’t matter much, as the only way they could jump again is by pressing the button again within a VERY small time frame, making their second jump just about inconsequential. But we could still make this impossible by moving the circle up a bit so the bottom of the circle is at the bottom of the player’s feet. But, anyway, you’re welcome for the help! Glad you figured it out.