# My script is making the player to jump continuously and I want to make it to jump once or twice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was trying to make a movement script for my project but I have a problem. Right now the code is working good for mobile and pc but there is just one small problem that I can't really resolve it, basically I'm stuck. For mobile if you press the touch screen the player will use the velocity and will go up until you remove the finger from screen. What I really want is to make something to  jump maximum once or probably twice when the finger is touching the display of the phone instead of going on Y axis up in heaven.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A reference to the rigidbody component
    /// </summary>
    private Rigidbody rb;

    [Tooltip("How fast is goes side ways")]
    public float dodgeSpeed;
    
    public float jumpForce;
   
    [Tooltip("How fast is goes forward!")]
   // [Range(0,20)]
    public float rollSpeed;
    float dirX;
 
 
  

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame

    void Update()
    {
        dirX = Input.acceleration.x * dodgeSpeed;
       
        var horizontalSpeed = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * dodgeSpeed;

       
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(horizontalSpeed + dirX, jumpForce, rollSpeed);
           
        }
          else 
        {
            rb.AddForce(horizontalSpeed + dirX, 0, rollSpeed);
        }
        
     
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(horizontalSpeed + dirX, jumpForce, rollSpeed);

        }
        else
        {
            rb.AddForce(horizontalSpeed + dirX, 0, rollSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt of preventing that ...

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [TouchPhase](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.html). In Update, you can check the phase and only jump if it's just began:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector3(horizontalSpeed + dirX, jumpForce, rollSpeed);
}
```

Comment: Yes that resolved half of my problem(if I hold the finger on screen is jumping once), but if I still press 10 times in a row the player will still go up. What I really want is to jump once or maximum twice when the player is on ground. Right now if I press on the screen when the player is in the air it's still going up instead of doing nothing...

Comment: @andr3y38 that would be better to ask in a separate question, since it's a separate problem. But don't bother asking and getting closed as duplicate - use those as reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54490384/question-about-double-jump-and-collision-in-unity and https://answers.unity.com/questions/1411531/how-to-jump-on-only-ground-colliders.html
To sum it up, you need to detect collision with ground and keep counter of how many times you jumped without touching ground, and stop adding velocity when that counter is more then one or two.